# Stripe using Ajax success but returns empty

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, stripe-payments

I have a strange error, i have 2 options for the user to either use stripe or paypal. I am also using bootstrapvalidator for error checking.

When i submit the form with the "paypal" option checked i get a correct response from the php file.

But when i submit the form with the "stripe" option check, i get a response in the console.log but its empty

Here is the part of the js

```
if(payment == 'stripe'){
            Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_sXTC8mAZ3Z9oiA0fMovYyOdX'); 

            Stripe.createToken({
                number: $('#card-number').val(),
                cvc: $('#card-cvc').val(),
                exp_month: $('#card-expiry-month').val(), 
                exp_year: $('#card-expiry-year').val()
            }, function(status, response) {
                if (response.error) {

                    alert(response.error.message);

                } else {
                    // token contains id, last4, and card type

                    var token = response['id'];

                    datastring = 'fullname=' + $('#fullname').val() + '&email=' + $('#email').val() + '&payment=' + payment + '&token=' + token;
                }
            });

        } else {
            // user checked paypal option
            datastring = 'fullname=' + $('#fullname').val() + '&email=' + $('#email').val() + '&payment=' + payment;
        }


        $.ajax({
            url: 'process.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: datastring,
            success: function(result){
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
```

here is the process.php file

```
    if($_POST){

        $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $token = $_POST['token'];
        $payment = $_POST['payment'];

    if($payment == 'stripe'){
            // Validate Stripe
            require 'lib/Stripe.php';

            $stripe = array(
                "secret_key"      => "my key",
                "publishable_key" => "my publishable key"
            );

            Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['secret_key']);

            echo 'Using stripe';

        } else {
            // Validate Paypal
            echo "Using Paypal";
        }
}
```

so when i check "stripe" option and submit, i should be getting "using stripe" instead im getting a empty response. Iv checked the datastring and the token is ok, and im not getting any errors. Any ideas?

Comment: You may try passing your data as an object, ex. {fullName: $('#fullname').val(), ...

Comment: have to send data to your server in success callback of Stripe API call. It is asynchronous. You create the data string there but your ajax will fire before that string is even created